# Backbone.js with php interaction

Tags: backbone.js, javascriptmvc

I have tried to create the user interaction page with backbone.js & php. But I can't able to call the function when i submit the html form. Anyone can assist me?

Here are the code

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone.js"></script>

    <!--- Here are the backbone code --->

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var FamilyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
       defaults: { 
         name: "Corleone" 
       },
       url: "back.php"
     }); 

     var FamilyList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       model: FamilyModel 
     });


    var FamilyListView = Backbone.View.extend({  
        el: $('#SampleForm'),
        model: FamilyModel,
        events: {
          'click #Submit': 'createOne'
        },
        createOne: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

           alert('Yes');
        }

     });

  // Fire up the application:
  window.App = new FamilyListView;
    </script>

<!-- //HTML -->
<form name="SampleForm" id="SampleForm">
<table>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="varName"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Age:</td><td><input type="text" name="intAge"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mobile:</td><td><input type="text" name="intMobile"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="ADD"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Expecting your valuable response ASAP.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to delay the calling of your `$('#SampleForm')` selector until the DOM is ready.

Backbone objects are defined with object literals, which means the value on the right is evaluated immediately. Since it's evaluated immediately, the DOM is not ready and jQuery cant find your form.

I wrote up a detailed explanation of the problem and some possible solutions, here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/

Comment: Derick, Thanks for spending your valuable time for me.

Answer (score 1):

---

You cannot call jquery there because the DOM is not created. 
Initialize your FamilyListView when the DOM is ready and your code should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var foo = new FamilyListView({el: $('form')});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response. Now I was struggled with getting HTML form input values to pass to server using Backbone.sync

// Here are the code
var str = $("#SampleForm").serializeArray();
  e.preventDefault();

     alert(str);
     var familymembers = new FamilyList(str);
     familymembers.each(function(member){
        Backbone.sync("create", member, {succ:function(e){ alert(e); }});
        });

Please assist me

Thanks in advance